# How can I find a puzzle the user has not yet solved in my Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a simple puzzle game to learn Rails 4. I have two models in my Rails app, Users and Puzzles. I'm trying to understand how to structure the two models so that I can keep track of the puzzles a User has solved and be able to find an unsolved puzzle for him to play. The puzzles do NOT have to be solved in any order, so my app just needs to be able to find ANY puzzle the user has not yet solved.

One obvious way is to create a many-to-many relationship between Users and Puzzles and create an attribute on the User model that stores the IDs of puzzles he's already solved, then use a simple DB query to find a puzzle ID not in that list, but that feels inefficient...

```
#Untested code, apologies for typos/bugs

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :solved_puzzles, class_name: "Puzzle"

  def unsolved_puzzle
    solved_puzzle_ids = self.solved_puzzles.map {|p| p.id}
    unsolved_puzzle = self.puzzles.where("id NOT IN ?", solved_puzzle_ids).first
  end
end

class Puzzle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :solved_by, class_name: "User"
end
```

Are there any problems with this approach? Other thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: If you're trying to avoid the extra db hit then you could simply add a boolean column on puzzles to determine whether it was solved or not.  But I think your way is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use has_and_belongs_to_many you can only store the link between user and puzzles. I would prefer has_many :through association where you can save the state of the puzzle for that particular user . The relationship between an user and a puzzle now have a separate class with solved state.
(Untested code)

```
class User
  has_many :user_puzzles
  has_many :puzzles, through: user_puzzles

  def unsolved_puzzle    
    user_puzzles.where(solved: false).first
  end

end

class UserPuzzle
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :puzzle
  #has attribute solved
end

class Puzzle
  has_many :user_puzzles
  has_many :users, through: user_puzzles
end
```